# Certain mp3 files create zip error

Tags: php, zip

I've been trying to make a zip archive for some mp3s. The problem I have is that some of the mp3s just break the zipping process, in bizarre ways. If I don't include one of these files everything is fine; if I put one of them in then it goes pear-shaped.

Ultimately, I want to put the zip file on my server for people to download, and I would like to make it on the fly using php. If I don't include any of my problematic files in the archive, it works fine. If I do, then I get a '500 internal server error', but nothing in the server error log. By creating my own error log for every step of the process, it's at the point I try and do zip->close that it seems to be failing.

I tried taking a step back, and making the zip archive locally using 7zip. If I include a problem file I can do this, but if I upload this zip archive to the server and then download it, the download is corrupt. If I don't include a problem file, it's fine. The same happens with winzip.

In total I have about 100 mp3s, of which about 6 cause this behaviour. They all have the same permissions, they all exist, they're all in the same directory, they're all roughly th same size. I even tried making the mp3 again from the source .wav file - the same thing happened with the new version.

I'm completely stumped. I've searched all over, and can't find any clues whatsoever. Help!!

Comment: The best way would be to get hold of the exact error message. You're likely to be looking in the wrong error log, a 500 error *must* be recorded somewhere (unless the server itself is badly misconfigured.)

Comment: As @Pekka웃 has said, getting the logs is the key. I suspect the MP3 filenames will have non-ASCII characters or spaces in them

Comment: I can't get the error message - the shared hosting doesn't provide the apache error log, and if I log it myself nothing is recorded. There aren't non ASCII characters in the filename, though there are spaces in some (but not all) of the problematic files. However, there are also spaces in many of the files which don't cause a problem.

Comment: If you activate error reporting in the PHP file, then you should be able to run it and see what error comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Several reasons are possible (and they can happen together): (a) buggy code in PHP zip creation - either in your code or in code that does actual compression , (b) text mode used in uploading or downloading the files.

As you see yourself, using 7zip solves the problem with PHP zip, so there must be some error in compression code. Now if you put created ZIPs and they are downloaded as broken, this can mean that the file is provided using text mode.

One of the non-obvious reasons is enabled mbcs functions overloads in PHP. With overloads enabled, strlen and similar functions, when binary data is passed to them, start to produce unexpected results (this is because they treat input as UTF8 strings).